# is Pushstate inferior to Hashbangs when it comes to caching?

Tags: ajax, html, browser-cache, pushstate, hashbang

There are several advantages to the HTML5 Pushstate in comparison to hasbangs, in fact, Google is now [encouraging the use of Pushstate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiAF9VdvRPw). The only Pushstate disadvantage being publicly discussed is the fact that non-modern browsers do not support it. However, to me it seems that Pushstate is also disadvantageous when it comes to caching. I might be wrong, hence this question.

**is Pushstate inferior to Hashbangs when it comes to caching pages?**

Here is a case where it seems that Pushstate is bad at caching.

**Pushsate**

- Bob navigates to `eg.com/page1`, the full page is downloaded, rendered and cached.
- Bob clicks a button, `eg.com/json/page2` is downloaded and cached.
- The browser Processes the JSON and re-renders parts of Bob's page.
- Pushstate changes the displayed browser address to `eg.com/page2`.
- Bob closes the browser, then re-opens it and directly visits
  `eg.com/pushstate2`. The full page is downloaded, rendered and cached.*

*-*Despite the fact that it is already theoretically available in the cache under the guise of `eg.com/json/page2`*

**Hashbangs**

- Alice navigates to `eg.com/#!page1`, `eg.com/index.html` is downloaded and cached.
- `eg.com/json/page1` is downloaded and cached.
- The browser Processes the JSON and renders Alice's page.
- Alice clicks a button, `eg.com/json/page2` is downloaded and cached, the displayed browser address is changed to `eg.com/#!page2`
- The browser Processes the JSON and renders Alice's page.
- Alice closes the browser, then re-opens it and directly visits `eg.com/#!page2`. **NOTHING is downloaded and everything is loaded from cache**, unlike Pushstate.

*Summary*

I have numerous similar cases in mind, The question is whether or not this is indeed valid, I may be missing something which is leading me to wrong conclusions. is Pushstate inferior to Hashbangs when it comes to caching pages?

Answer (score 0):

I think that pushstate is inferior, but if you are building a SPA page correctly the differences should not be significant:

Assuming that you are using one of the latest frameworks, your `index.html` page should be relatively small with a few `<script>` tags (frameworks like webpack, systemjs etc).
The js files that are referenced with these tags do get cached normally so the only difference between the two methods is fetching `index.html` for every pushstate url as opposed to fetching it once in hashbang mode.

I got the idea from the following question:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65694/is-this-way-of-using-pushstate-seo-friendly